# Get random slice/fraction of a list in python

Tags: python, random, slice, probability

Imagine we have the following list:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now we want a random fraction of the previous list, i.e., a random sublist of length `len(l) * frac`. Therefore, if `frac=0.2` the output list should have length `2` (0.2 x 10).

The following results are expected:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l_new = sample(list=l, frac=0.3) # [4, 6, 8]
l_new = sample(list=l, frac=0.6) # [0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

How can I achieve this behaviour? I have looked at [random.sample](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/), however it works by supplying a number of elements rather than a fraction of elements.

Comment: The question can be closed. I've already tackled it :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use `random.sample` with `k = int(len(l) * frac)`, like so:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
frac = 0.3
l = random.sample(l, int(len(l) * frac))

print(l)
>>> [4, 7, 9]
```

Using it as a function:

```
# Randomly Sample a fraction of elements from a list
def random_sample(l, frac=0.5):
    return random.sample(l, int(len(l) * frac))
```